# InfoWindow graphics "messed up" using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm simply putting a marker on the map (after it's all set up and centered like in the sample code in the Google documentation) using geocoder and place an infoWindow on it like so:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: title
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            console.log('openInfoWindow');
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    };
});
```

`content` is just an HTML link, `address` is a valid address (since I have no problem showing the marker).

As you can see on this picture, I have a little graphical problem:

[image: messed up InfoWindow]

It's like the css sprite is all… messed up. I have no idea where this problem comes from, have been on it for a while now and I'm getting annoyed… any guess is helpful at this point. The screen capture is the same in Webkit (Safari & Chrome) and Firefox.

Comment: Does `<Ctrl>+<F5>` help?

Comment: @mkilmanas I tried. Many, many times. I cleared the cache too.

Comment: Weird. Maybe then you should double-check if you don't have coliding css declarations (i.e. same ids or classes) - which is not very likely, but still worth a ckeck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like [mkilmanas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316228/mkilmanas) guessed, it was a colliding CSS declaration. I had this in my CSS file:

```
img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

I am fully aware of how stupid that was. Thanks a lot [mkilmanas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316228/mkilmanas).

Comment: I had the exact same problem when trying to use Google Maps within Twitter's bootstrap CSS framework. For some reason they were setting `max-width: 100%;` in bootstrap.css. Overriding the `img` css definition within the scope of my map container fixed everything.

Comment: I had the same experience with Twitter bootstrap. The related issues is: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3575.

Answer (score 14):

This is old, but here is a more general solution from the [github issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2410):

```
img[src*="gstatic.com/"], img[src*="googleapis.com/"]  {
    max-width: 99999px;
}
```

Comment: Indeed this fixes the bootstrap issue!

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was having the same problem and it was really annoying :p